# Is there a way of passing a multidimensional array into a session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, multidimensional-array

I've been trying with this issue all morning. When i load the function which sets the array directly, and remove the redirect, it works fine. All of the data in both levels of the array is there. When i add back in the redirect, the function redirects and the second level of the array is removed. Leaving just the first. So the Session is setting, but it's dropping the data from the session for some reason.

**The Function Which controls the array and redirect**

```
public function test(){
        $i=$_GET['i'];
        $this->construct_data();
        redirect('view/name?i='$i);
    }
public function construct_data(){
    $i=$_GET['i'];
    list($array1)=$this->array1($i);
    list($array2)=$this->array2($i);
    list($array3)=$this->array3($i);
    list($array4)=$this->array4($i);
    list($array5)=$this->array5($i);
    list($array6)=$this->array6($i);
    $container= array(
            'array1'=>$array1,
            'array2'=>$array2,
            'array3'=>$array2,
            'array4'=>$array4,
            'array5'=>$array5
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata('construct',$container);
}
```

**The view**

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('construct');
var_dump($data);
```

The var_dump in the view returns all of the first level of container, array 1 through 5. But it doesn't contain any of the data inside of the functions that are called. it returns $data['array1'].

Now if i were to put the var_dump inside the test function instead of redirect, the data is returned as it should be, $data['array1']['array1item'].

Let me know if this was unclear. Also the names of variables and functions were changed to maintain anonymity.

Comment: serialization is the answer

Comment: `serialization is the answer` - That's what php's session mechanism does for you automagically.....

Comment: `list($array1)=$this->array1($i);` - after this $array1 "is" only the first element of the array returned by `$this->array1($i)`, e.g. if $this->array1($i) returns `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` $array1 will be ===`1`

Comment: you can use `json_encode` to store and `json_decode` to get

Comment: `you can use json_encode to store and json_decode to get` - not the answer to this question. Again: the session mechanism performs the serialization automagically for you - in this particular case there's no need for serialize(), json_**code(), yaml_emit() or any of the other serialization functions.

Comment: @VolkerK Try to understand what OP wants. He want to store arrays inside one session variable at codeigniter and using `json_encode ` and `json_decode` he can do it.

Comment: I do understand, and json_encode isn't needed. `$_SESSION['foo'] = array('bar'=>array('moo'=>array('mae'=>array(1,2,3,4))));` does just that.

Comment: @VolkerK it will not work at codeigniters way.see doc https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @VolkerK sorry my mistake.I see it works without json_**code.`$this->session->set_userdata('construct',$container);` this code works.But codeigniter docs does not cover it.

Comment: @VolkerK That's exactly what i want. The problem is the session 'drops' the parameters inside of the array. So to change what you wrote, even though it's not CI. `$_SESSION['foo'] =  array('bar'=>NULL); ` is what is actually stored in the session, not `$SESSION['foo'] = array('bar'=>array('moo'=>'info'));` The problem is that the second level of the array, i.e. moo is only available within the controller it is created within. For some reason the session drops moo when it is called to another controller.

Comment: @Bakitai I see it works in same controller and another controller.Check you may be reset the session value somewhere else.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I've checked this. It does work inside the same controller. I even made several functions which called each other, and the session still set. I've also checked if the session is reset and it is not. It's setting the session in the first level array, it's just not keeping the second level array when outside of the controller.

Comment: `array(5) { ["array1"]=> NULL ["array2"]=> array(0) { } ["array3"]=> array(0) { } ["array4"]=> NULL ["array5"]=> NULL } ` This is what the var_dump on the session returns.

Comment: @Bakitai have you seen my second comment? The comment about the `list(...)` constructs in your code. That's not the problem? You're sure? Because you've double-tripple-quadruple-checked?

Comment: 1. How can i check? 2. I'm fairly certain, since it's a different function all together that is accessing the session (and works) but when it's another class accessing, it won't work.

Comment: Found a workaround. I just set multiple sessions. So it's not a multidimensional array anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding array directly to session, first convert it into json by using json_encode() function. On retrieving you have decode it by using json_decode() function.

**Add** **To** **session**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('construct',json_encode($container));
```

**Reading** **From** **Session**

```html
$data = $this->session->userdata('construct');
var_dump(json_decode($data,true));
```

Comment: _SESSION itself is serialized. Doing it yourself by hand for some elements is just adding superfluous complexity.

Comment: I don't think this is wrong answer.I think OP wants store array inside one session variable and this is the solution.

Comment: This doesn't work since json_decode is expecting a string. What i'm giving is array(array(string)).

Comment: You have to use json_encode while storing array into session. Then json_decode will work.

Comment: i did. `Warning:json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` 

Controller:

`$this->session->set_userdata('construct',json_encode($container_array));`


view: 

`$data = $this->session->userdata('construct');
var_dump(json_decode($data,true));`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the actual problem was size. I was making it too big and as a result it couldn't pass it outside of the class.